# Update helm chart with additional properties

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

We are using the [prometheus operator chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator)

Currently, Im creating my own `values.yaml` that im overriding the default values from the chart like

`helm install po -f values.yaml stable/prometheus-operator -n po`

There is a Grafana properties which I need to modify as the opertor come with grafana properties

https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml#L486

However, I want to modify properties that is not in the `values.yaml` of the prometheus chart and found here:
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L422 (there is a reference on the chart)

My question is assume I want to modify the `client_id` , what is the **recommended way** to do it?
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the values of dependent charts by using the name of the dependency (which for `grafana` in the `prometheus` chart can be found [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/requirements.yaml)) as another key within the `values.yml`.

In thise case, it is just `grafana` and so to overwrite it in your `values.yml`, do it like this:

```
# ... config of the original prometheus chart

# overwrite grafana's yaml by using the dependency name
grafana:
  grafana.ini:
    auth.github:
      client_id: 'what you need to put here'
```

Comment: And how can I modify to add Athena as Datasource allow_loading_unsigned_plugins